# How can I use the find_one() function with the _id key?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

Let's say I have a MongoDB database where I want to check whether a user is logged in or not by using a cookie with the ID of an entry in the `users` database. For simplicity, let's have it as a simple variable `foo = bar`.

How can I do a `find_one()` query to the database using the `_id` as the query item?

Here's an example of what I have in mind, in code:

```
foo = bar
userLoggedIn = users.find_one({'_id':ObjectId(foo)})
print(userLoggedIn)
```

Comment: What happens when you try that?

Comment: I get `NameError: name 'ObjectId' is not defined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you're importing `ObjectId` by including the following in your file: `from bson.objectid import ObjectId`.

Comment: Thanks! All I had to do next is convert the ObjectId into a string, so I can compare it later down the line.